# Passing data from upper foreach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-generation, t4

I have code for a T4 template that has two for each loops, and one is inside the other.

I am having an issue escaping the inner for each and pass data from the parent for each.

The image below demonstrates the variable data I am trying to pass from the parent for each to the child for each.

I have tried:

```
foreach (var prop in GetPropertiesNameOfClass(#><#=item #><#))
foreach (var prop in GetPropertiesNameOfClass(#>item<#))
```

when I transform the template it generates an error:

- CS1525 error Invalid expression term ')'
- CS1002 error ; expected

[image]

Comment: It was as simple as that and I thought I tried that but clearly I did not. I wish I could mark your comment as the answer because it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already inside of `<# #>` context, so you does not need any additional escaping to refer to `item` variable in your code:

```
foreach (var prop in GetPropertiesNameOfClass(item))
```